# Using Conditional Inside a ForEach view to apply different effects to each view

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to render a list of items in an array. The array items are structs with a String and an Integer. I'd like items in the array with an Integer greater than 0 to be aligned to the left, equal to 0 to be center aligned, and less than 0 aligned to the right. In the future I'd like to be able to apply some other differences but for now the different alignment is all I need.

I have tried using a ForEach view to loop over the items in the array and have an if else statement to try two different ways of displaying it but I am getting an error that () cannot comfort to 'View'.

Edit: Adding the exact error message: `Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`

This is the struct that I am looping over in the ForEach:

```
struct PreviouslyPlayedData: Hashable {
        let text: String
        let speaker: Int
    }
```

Here is the ForEach that I have set up right now, it is giving errors.

```
ForEach(previouslyPlayed, id: \.self) { data in
                if (data.speaker == 0) {
                    Text(data.text)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: nil, alignment: .center)
                } else {
                    Text(data.text)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: nil, alignment: .leading)
                }

            }
```

Comment: What errors is it giving?

Comment: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Answer (score 4):

You can't use conditionals in `ForEach`.

SwiftUI does a lot behind the scenes and it simply expects that only one very specific type of View is contained in your `ContentView`. It doesn't care WHICH type of view (hence the `-> some View`), but it does care that only one type can ever be returned. And while sometimes you can guarantee that in your conditionals, Swift can't quite grok it out for you.

You've got a number of options to work around this. If your logic is relatively simple and you don't need to modify much, you can use the ternary operator to switch the styling:

```
ForEach(previouslyPlayed, id: \.self) { data in
    Text(data.text)
    .frame(width: 300, height: nil, alignment: data.speaker == 0 ? .center : .leading)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to display each item in it's own view, which can handle the alignment according to the item, and use the main content view to display a list:

For example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PreviouslyPlayedData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // To make it easier to use in lists
    let text: String
    let speaker: Int

    static var previewItems: [PreviouslyPlayedData] {
        [PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "First", speaker: -1),
         PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "Second", speaker: -1),
         PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "third", speaker: 0),
         PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "Fourth", speaker: 1),
         PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "Fifth", speaker: -1),
         PreviouslyPlayedData(text: "Sixth", speaker: 2),
        ]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items = PreviouslyPlayedData.previewItems

    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            DataView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct DataView: View {
    let item: PreviouslyPlayedData

    var itemAlignment: Alignment {
        if item.speaker < 0 {
            return .leading
        } else if item.speaker == 0 {
            return .center
        } else {
            return .trailing
        }
    }


    var body: some View {
        Text(item.text).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: itemAlignment)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Which looks like:

[image]